# Stop pandas to_excel() prepending apostrophe on strings

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which has only strings, although some are date strings like '2019-01-01', others are ints or bools as strings such as '1084' and 'FALSE'. When I try to write this to a sheet in an xlsx file I find it is prepending apostrophes in some cases, presumably to stop excel trying to evaluate the dates/ints/bools and so on.

Is there a way to stop this? I need to upload this generated .xlsx to a system which will reject it if these apostrophes are there.

Currently I import a xlsx file as a template which has two sheets and I want to overwrite the 2nd one.

Export code snippet:

```py
exp_dict['ScheduleDetails'] = df
with pd.ExcelWriter(f"{uploads_folder}{name}_FORMATTED.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter', options={'encoding':'utf-8'}) as writer:
   for k,v in exp_dict.items():
       v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = k, index = False)
```

Comment: If you write a string type, pandas will make sure it is still interpreted as a string. If you want to write it as an int, bool, date, etc, you may just want to update your dataframe columns to be of the correct type

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The dataframe definitely has the correct dtypes. I solved this by just writing to csv and importing again, which is a dirty hack (and as such I am not posting it as a proper solution) but seems to make the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is but if you want to convertdtypes to str the try this:

```
  df.astype({'col_name': 'str'})
```